# Out Bound Dialing Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I have a calling application developed in PHP with AGI on Asterisk framework, below is the basic flow of application.

```
We receive a call from user at our Asterisk ss7  server and forward the same call to another user from our server.
```

I want to know the status of call forward to another user. Status means what happen with call between both users e.g. Hangup, Busy, Not Answered etc.

Comment: use ${CDR(disposition)} to get the call status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much detail on how you are placing the call or anything else but if you are performing a Dial() and want to know at the end of the call the result try ${DIALSTATUS}.

This will contain something like 'ANSWER', 'NOANSWER' or 'BUSY'. For the full list and more info check out http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variable+DIALSTATUS

Answer (score 0):

you can use CDR feature or use a diaplan to get the dialed status

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variable+DIALSTATUS

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cdr+mysql

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes